# Normalizing eigenvectors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, software

Over the course of this quantum class I'm taking I've run into issues with properly normalizing my eigenvectors.

Here is my TA's explanation of this particular example is done. I am lost as to where these $x+y=ax$, $x-y=ay$, and $x^2 +y^2 =1$ conditions in their solutions come from.

[image]
[image]

The eigenvalues are easy via Mathematica or a characteristic equation, but the "normalized" eigenvectors Mathematica gives do not match up:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciate and would hopefully clear things up for me during my studying today before the final tomorrow.

Comment: You can check if two expressions are equal by typing `expr1 - expr2 // Simplify` which should give zero. Did you check if these vectors are actually the right answer?

Comment: I checked this and indeed they are not equal :/ So my TA's solutions are incorrect? :(

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s about checking the workings of a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations $x + y = ax$ and $x - y = ay$ are obtained by the following.
$$\begin{aligned}
A \left( \begin{matrix}x \\ y \end{matrix}\right ) &= a\left( \begin{matrix}x \\ y \end{matrix}\right )\\[1.0em]
\left( \begin{matrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1  \end{matrix}\right )\left( \begin{matrix}x \\ y \end{matrix}\right )&=a\left( \begin{matrix}x \\ y \end{matrix}\right )
\end{aligned}$$
Do the matrix multiplication and you get in the first line the first expression and in the second line the second expression.

$y  = (\sqrt2 -1) x $ is obtained by adding the first line and the second, pluging in $a=\sqrt2$ and rearanging for $y$.

$$\begin{aligned}
2x  &= a(x+y) \\
 \frac{2}{a}x -x &= y \\
\left(\frac{2}{a}-1 \right)x &= y \\
a &=\sqrt 2\\
(\sqrt 2  -1 )x&=y
\end{aligned}$$
That means that your eigenvector with eigenvalue $a=\sqrt 2$ is proportional to a vector of the form
$$
\left( \begin{matrix}x \\ y \end{matrix} \right)_{a=\sqrt 2} = x_{a=\sqrt 2} \left( \begin{matrix}1 \\ \sqrt 2 -1 \end{matrix} \right)
$$
The last free parameter $x_{a=\sqrt 2}$  is fixed by the normalization condition
$$
\left( \begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix} \right)_{a=\sqrt 2} \cdot \left( \begin{matrix}x \\ y \end{matrix} \right)_{a=\sqrt 2} = 1
$$
where i have omitted complex conjugation of the left vector since everything is real. The normalization condition is the same as the equation $x^2 + y^2 = 1 $.

Plugging the results in we get
$$\begin{aligned}
x^2_{a=\sqrt 2} &= \frac{1}{\left( \begin{matrix}1 \\ \sqrt 2 -1 \end{matrix} \right)\cdot \left( \begin{matrix}1 \\ \sqrt 2 -1 \end{matrix} \right)} \\[1.0em]
x^2_{a=\sqrt 2} &= \frac{1}{4-2\sqrt 2} \\
x_{a=\sqrt 2} &= \sqrt{\frac{1}{4-2\sqrt 2}}
\end{aligned}$$

With this we have all parts to write down our first normed eigenvector belonging to eigenvalue $a=\sqrt 2 $,
$$
\vec a_{\sqrt 2} =\sqrt{\frac{1}{4-2\sqrt 2}}\left( \begin{matrix}1 \\ \sqrt 2 -1 \end{matrix} \right)
$$
All that remains to get the same solution as your TA is some algebra.

$$\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{\frac{1}{4-2\sqrt 2}} &= \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2-\sqrt 2}} \\
&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\frac{ 2 +\sqrt 2 }{ (2-\sqrt 2)(2 + \sqrt 2) }} \\
&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\frac{ 2 +\sqrt 2 }{ 2 }} \\ 
&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right) } \\ 
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sqrt{ 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}  \\ 
\end{aligned}$$

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sqrt{ 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}}( \sqrt 2 -1) &=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \sqrt{ \left(\frac{\sqrt 2 + 1}{\sqrt 2}\right)(\sqrt 2 -1)^2 } \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sqrt{ \frac{\sqrt 2 -1}{\sqrt 2} } \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sqrt{ 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} } \\
\end{aligned}$$

With this we can write the vector as
$$\begin{aligned}
\vec a_{\sqrt 2} &=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4-2\sqrt 2}}\left( \begin{matrix}1 \\ \sqrt 2 -1 \end{matrix} \right) \\[1.4em]
\vec a_{\sqrt 2} &=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \left( \begin{matrix} \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}} \\ \sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}} \end{matrix}\right)
\end{aligned}$$

This is how $|a_1\rangle$ is obtained.

It is also important to remember that the phase of an eigenvector is arbitrary. Generally, if we allow complex coefficients, we can multiply an eigenvector with any complex number of magnitude 1 without changing anything. Limiting ourselves to reals, that leaves only the choice for the phase of  $1$ or $-1$. That means is could just as well use $-1|a_1 \rangle$ as eigenvector belonging to eigenvalue $a_1$. This can also lead to different looking results when two people compare their results.

You can also bring the solution into the form of your output via some algebra,

$$\begin{aligned}
\vec a_{\sqrt 2} &=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4-2\sqrt 2}}\left( \begin{matrix}1 \\ \sqrt 2 -1 \end{matrix} \right) \\[1.4em]
&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4-2\sqrt 2}} \frac{(1+\sqrt 2)}{(1+\sqrt 2)} \left( \begin{matrix}1 \\ \sqrt 2 -1 \end{matrix} \right) \\[1.4em]
&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4-2\sqrt 2}} \frac{1}{(1+\sqrt 2)} \left( \begin{matrix}1+\sqrt 2 \\ (1+\sqrt 2)(\sqrt 2 -1) \end{matrix} \right) \\[1.4em]
&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4-2\sqrt 2}} \frac{1}{(1+\sqrt 2)} \left( \begin{matrix}1+\sqrt 2 \\ 2-1 \end{matrix} \right) \\[1.4em]
&=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4-2\sqrt 2}} \frac{1}{(1+\sqrt 2)} \left( \begin{matrix}1+\sqrt 2 \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right) \\[1.4em]
\end{aligned}$$

As you see that form is proportional to the result that you got, which means that the result that your TA got is the same, its only hard to see due to the algebra with the normalization factor.

After playing a bit more with the algebra, we can show that it is exactly the same as the result that you got,
$$\begin{aligned}
(1+\sqrt 2) \sqrt{4-2\sqrt 2} &= \sqrt{(1+\sqrt 2)^2(4-2\sqrt 2)  } \\
&=\sqrt{(3+2\sqrt 2 )(4-2\sqrt 2)} \\
&=\sqrt{12+2\sqrt 2 - 8} \\
&=\sqrt{4+2\sqrt 2} \\
(1+\sqrt 2) \sqrt{4-2\sqrt 2}&= \sqrt{1 + (1+\sqrt 2)^2}
\end{aligned}$$

$$
\sqrt{\frac{1}{4-2\sqrt 2}} \frac{1}{(1+\sqrt 2)} \left( \begin{matrix}1+\sqrt 2  \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + (1+\sqrt 2)^2}
} \left( \begin{matrix}1+\sqrt 2 \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right)  
$$

Comment: WOW THANK YOU! I will spend some time rereading this carefully before asking questions :D